# Accessing labels within a LoginView

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using the asp.net LoginView to show different data to authenticated or anonymous users.

```
<asp:LoginView ID="LoginView1" Runat="server">
    <LoggedInTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Foo" runat="server" />
    </LoggedInTemplate>
    <AnonymousTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Bar" runat="server" />
    </AnonymousTemplate>
</asp:LoginView>
```

When I moved `Foo` and `Bar` into `LoginView1`, I was unable to access them from the code behind in this fashion:

```
Foo.Text = "I am Foo";
Bar.Text = "I am Bar";
```

I was able to access them in this fashion before moving them into the LoginView. What (clean) method can I use to access these labels?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use FindControl on the LoginView, and Cast appropriately as shown below:

```
var foo = (Label)LoginView1.FindControl("Foo");
foo.Text =  "I am Foo";
```

Comment: say I was trying to find a <li runat="server" ID="Foo"/>. do you know what I would cast that to?

Comment: Can you try "HtmlControl", or "HtmlGenericControl"?